# Apply shader to only a part of a sprite

Tags: xna, c#, shaders, xna-4.0, graphic-effects

I'm trying to make an image blur when a transparent image overlays it, I am wanting it only to blur the section that is being overlayed. So if half of the original image is not being overlapped, that half is not blurred but the rest is.

Un-blurred - Not overlapping https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9jsk.png

Fully Blurred - partially overlapping https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHLup.png

Game1.cs

```
namespace NewShaderTutorial 
{ 
  /// <summary> 
  /// This is the main type for your game 
  /// </summary> 
  public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game 
    { 
      GraphicsDeviceManager graphics; 
      SpriteBatch spriteBatch; 

    Effect blur; 
    Texture2D surge; 
    Rectangle surgeRectangle; 
    Texture2D bubble; 
    Rectangle bubbleRectangle; 
    private bool overlapping; 

    public Game1() 
    { 
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this); 
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content"; 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run. 
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic 
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components 
    /// and initialize them as well. 
    /// </summary> 
    protected override void Initialize() 
    { 
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here 

        base.Initialize(); 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load 
    /// all of your content. 
    /// </summary> 
    protected override void LoadContent() 
    { 
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures. 
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice); 

        surge = Content.Load<Texture2D>("surge"); 
        surgeRectangle = new Rectangle(250, 250, surge.Width, surge.Height); 

        bubble = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bubble - Red"); 
        bubbleRectangle = new Rectangle(250, 250, bubble.Width, bubble.Height); 

        blur = Content.Load<Effect>("blur"); 

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload 
    /// all content. 
    /// </summary> 
    protected override void UnloadContent() 
    { 
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world, 
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param> 
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) 
    { 
        // Allows the game to exit 
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed) 
            this.Exit(); 

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) 
            bubbleRectangle.X--; 
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) 
            bubbleRectangle.X++; 
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)) 
            bubbleRectangle.Y--; 
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down)) 
            bubbleRectangle.Y++; 

        blur.Parameters["blur"].SetValue(0.015f); 

        Overlapping(); 

        // TODO: Add your update logic here 

        base.Update(gameTime); 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param> 
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) 
    { 
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue); 

        if (overlapping == true) 
        { 

            spriteBatch.Begin(0, null, null, null, null, blur); 
            spriteBatch.Draw(surge, surgeRectangle, Color.White); 
            spriteBatch.End(); 
            //     spriteBatch.Begin(0, null, null, null, null, blur); 
            spriteBatch.Begin(); 
            spriteBatch.Draw(bubble, bubbleRectangle, Color.White); 
            spriteBatch.End(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            spriteBatch.Begin(); 
            spriteBatch.Draw(surge, surgeRectangle, Color.White); 
            spriteBatch.Draw(bubble, bubbleRectangle, Color.White); 
            spriteBatch.End(); 
        } 

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here 

        base.Draw(gameTime); 
    } 

    public void Overlapping() 
    { 
        float surgeDimensionX = surgeRectangle.X + surge.Width; 
        float surgeDimensionY = surgeRectangle.Y + surge.Height; 
        float bubbleDimensionX = bubbleRectangle.X + bubble.Width; 
        float bubbleDimensionY = bubbleRectangle.Y + bubble.Height; 

        if ((surgeRectangle.X >= (bubbleRectangle.X) && ((surgeRectangle.X <= (bubbleDimensionX))) && (surgeRectangle.Y >= (bubbleRectangle.Y)) && (surgeRectangle.Y <= (bubbleDimensionY)))) 
        { 
            overlapping = true; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            overlapping = false; 
        } 
        Console.WriteLine(overlapping); 
    } 
}
```

Blur.fx class

```
// TODO: add effect parameters here.  
sampler TextureSampler;  

float blur = 0.0015;  

struct PixelInput  
{  
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;  
};  

float4 PixelShaderFunction(PixelInput input) : COLOR0  
{  

    float4 color = tex2D(TextureSampler,  
    float2(input.TexCoord.x+blur, input.TexCoord.y+blur));  
color += tex2D( TextureSampler,  
    float2(input.TexCoord.x-blur, input.TexCoord.y-blur));  
color += tex2D( TextureSampler,  
    float2(input.TexCoord.x+blur, input.TexCoord.y-blur));  
color += tex2D( TextureSampler,  
    float2(input.TexCoord.x-blur, input.TexCoord.y+blur));  

color = color / 4;  
    return color;  
}  


technique Default  
{  
    pass P0  
    {  
        // TODO: set renderstates here.  

        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();  
    }  
}
```

So I'm wanting to get the partially overlapping part to only blur the section that is being overlapped not the whole sprite. Any help would be great, as I've been stuck on this for awhile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First draw your bubbles with basic shader to RenderTarget2D texture.
Next draw sprites shat should be blured with custom shader and pass it as BlurMapTexture paramether.
In this shader add sampler for blur map:

```
texture BlurMapTexture;
sampler2D blurMapSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = (BlurMapTexture);
    MagFilter = Point;
    MinFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};
```

Check is pixel from blur map is transparent then there should be no blur, if not transparent then blur should be applied.

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(PixelInput input) : COLOR0  
{
    float4 color;
    float4 blurMapColor = tex2D(blurMapSampler, texture)
    if (blurMapColor.a == 0)
    {
        color = tex2D(TextureSampler, input.TexCoord);
    }
    else
    {
        color = tex2D(TextureSampler,
            float2(input.TexCoord.x + blur, input.TexCoord.y + blur));
        color += tex2D(TextureSampler,
            float2(input.TexCoord.x - blur, input.TexCoord.y - blur));
        color += tex2D(TextureSampler,
            float2(input.TexCoord.x + blur, input.TexCoord.y - blur));
        color += tex2D(TextureSampler,
            float2(input.TexCoord.x - blur, input.TexCoord.y + blur));
        color = color / 4;
    }

    return color;  
}
```

And then just draw texture with bubbles above blured image. I think it should works.

**Update**

I'm upload example project on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-4sbCAUVHrzLVNhUUtBXzlPTUE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Hi, I'm not to sure how to use rendertarget2d, would it be possible if you could give me a rolling start with how to do what you are telling me?

Comment: You can read this tutorial for start: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/render-to-texture. Later I'll add code snippet.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll give it a read and see if i can make any progress.

Comment: I'm udated my answer.

Comment: @Silveor Uploading an example is awesome. I would recommend uploading it to Github since it allows people to view and reference the code w/o downloading it.